# DJANGO как сделать запрос к двум таблицам/моделям, не связанных внешними/foreign ключами

Tags: html, sql, django, база-данных

Как возможно вывести в HTML сводные данные в одну таблицу из двух таблиц/моделей данных  не связанных внешними ключами (**Наподобие в SQL**: FROM po INNER JOIN table_1 ON table_1.id= table_2.id)

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    people_id = models.IntegerField()     # --- > поле совпадает с Obrazovanie
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    age = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Obrazovanie(models.Model):
    people_id = models.IntegerField()     # --- > поле совпадает с Teacher
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    name_university = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    date_birth = models.DateField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Как сделать запрос/sql в (Django Model) одновременно к двум моделям данных ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ---> Пример sql-запроса напрямую к базе данных/таблице без использования моделей данных

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * from teacher и тд")
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    logger.info(f"{row=}, {type(row)}")
```